# Using Xcode 7/Swift 2 writeToPath to Resources file the call does not fail but no data is written

Tags: swift, xcode, writetofile

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.0.  I am using the following code sample:

```
func writeToResourcesDataDir() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TestData", ofType: ".json") {
        let str = "Test String"
        do {
            try str.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("writeToFile successful")
        } catch {
            print("writeToFile failed")
        }
    } else {
        print("Path does not exist")
    }
}
```

Running under Xcode in the see the "writeToFile successful" message.
But, also using the simulator, I can display the TestData in the Resources directory and the file does not have the string.
I also used a terminal window in Mac to look at the files in the Resources directory and the TestData file is empty (0 bytes).
I know I am in the correct Resources directory because there is another file in the directory that has correct data that is used for running the other parts of the program.

I have spent several days now looking at other google entries about data from writeToFile not working and I have tried out every fix or things to try I have found.

Can anyone help?

I added code to accept the boolean return from the call to writeToFile and it returns a false. 
I'm not sure why a false is returned but the catch isn't invoked.
I am not sure how to get the error code that goes with this writeToFile in Swift 2.0.

I am also wondering if this is a write permissions problem.
Should I be using the Documents directory instead of the Data directory?

Comment: Firstly, you should print out the value of `path` to see where it's trying to write. Secondly, it looks like you're trying to write to a file inside your main bundle. This isn't going to work.

Comment: Path is  Optional("/Users/davidstallmo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FBF6DFD0-80B7-48A1-AB73-B049ABC94341/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CFF0C122-E178-4AE2-A1C9-83B24F51A38E/Halo.app/Introduction to Halo.json")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This is swift 2.3 and xcode 8.

```
let filename = "yourjsonfile"
let documentDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
let filePath = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
let fileExist = filePath?.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil)
if (fileExist == true) {
    print("Found file")
} else {
    print("File not found")
}
```

Comment: So, indeed, the problem was using the data dir instead of the documents dir.  writeToFile to a file in that directory works and the data shows up.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I use this snippet of code to check whether I have a Facebook-profile image from the friends-list or not. If the answer solves your issue you may mark it as such. Regards